# when does javascript decide to change object to string

Tags: javascript

I have this code bellow :

```
var obj2 = {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    if (hint == 'number') {
      return 10;
    }
    if (hint == 'string') {
      return 'hello';
    }
    return true;
  }
};
```

When i call `console.log(`${obj2}`);` then function ( Symbol.toPrimitive ) get called with hint = string

I want to know what are the other cases where javascript decide to call symbol.toPrimitive with the argument 'string'

Comment: whenever obj2 is "coerced" to be a string .. `"" + obj2` for example

Comment: @Bravo can you give more details please , in case of( ""+obj2) [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) get  called with hint = default

Comment: I misunderstood the question :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used any time the code uses an operation that "coerces" (implicitly converts) the object to a *string*, specifically, rather than leaving the decision of what kind of primitive it should be to the object (`hint` = `"default"`).

There aren't all that many since, again, `"default"` is more commonly used. The obvious one is explicit conversion to string: `String(obj)`. Other than that, they're mostly around turning a value into a property name. For example if you use an object like this:

```
someOtherObject[obj] = value;
```

...`obj` is [converted to string](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-topropertykey) in order to be used as a property name.

```js
const obj = {
    [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
        console.log(`hint = ${hint}`);
        if (hint == 'number') {
            return 10;
        }
        if (hint == 'string') {
            return 'hello';
        }
        return true;
    }
};

const otherObject = {};
otherObject[obj] = "some value";
console.log(`otherObject.hello = ${otherObject.hello}`);
```

For a definitive list of when this happens implicitly, see [the specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/) looking for places where the abstract [`ToPrimitive`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive) operation is used with the argument `string` and the places where the abstract [ToString](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tostring) operation is used. Naturally, code outside the definition of the spec (like `console.log`) can call the method explicitly as well.

> When i call `console.log(${obj2});` then `function ( Symbol.toPrimitive )` get called with `hint` = string

Not with all consoles. Some consoles just output their own representation of the object, without converting to string.

Comment: "Naturally, code outside the definition of the spec (like console.log) can call the method explicitly as well." Yes, all Web APIs that take a DOMString as input [will call `ToString()` on the input](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#es-DOMString). So, while `console.log` shouldn't call it, `alert(msg)` will.