# From where is the argument hint in [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) taken?

Tags: javascript

What is happening between for example alert(+user); and its method deciding that hint is 'number'? So far I can't explain it other than "oh they tried to converse it to a number, so let's do that". I would like to know how that actually looks like.

```js
let user = {
  name: "John",
  money: 1000,

  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    alert(`hint: ${hint}`);
    return hint == "string" ? `{name: "${this.name}"}` : this.money;
  }
};

// conversions demo:
alert(user); // hint: string -> {name: "John"}
alert(+user); // hint: number -> 1000
alert(user + 500); // hint: default -> 1500
```

Comment: Your explanation in quotes is pretty much it.

Comment: As explained in detail over on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive

Comment: Which only states "The function is called with a string argument hint, which specifies the preferred type of the result primitive value. The hint argument can be one of "number", "string", and "default".". And does not answer my question. I tried to look at the specification but I simply don't understand it.

Comment: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-toprimitive For the internal call to this method. For where does the conversion to string is done in the first alert(user), that's done at WebIDL level, the input to `alert(message)` is a DOMString, so your input is converted to a string in JS. Other ones are basic type conversions in JS.

Comment: This has already been asked here: [Rules for Symbol.toPrimitive argument](/q/46483925/4642212). Read the specification. Hover over the section header and click “References” to see where and how `Symbol.toPrimitive` is used.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not at a level to understand the specification. I would appreciate a little guidance if possible.

Comment: Almost dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847573/when-does-javascript-decide-to-change-object-to-string

Comment: @Kaiido The answer under that question is somewhat helpful, thank you.